# how does xhtml form data get passed to the managed bean?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, persistence

related to [When/where do entities get created on a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463499/when-where-do-entities-get-created-on-a-java-ee-web-application)

so how does the form data get passed to the managed bean? is after the entity get instantiated? it is just that, I can't seem to pass data from form to the managed bean. when i try to persist my entity, the error tells me everything is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case someone would encounter this confusion that I was in, here is what I did to the managed bean. my guess is, it gets created on the first access of an input field.

```
@ManagedBean
```

@RequestScoped
public class untitledController implements Serializable {

```
@EJB
UntitledFacade facade;
Untitled untitled;

/** Creates a new instance of untitledController */
public untitledController() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // create the entity object to be used 
    untitled = new Untitled();
}

public Untitled getSelected() {
    if (untitled == null) {
        System.out.println("created a new object");
        return new Untitled();
    } else {
        System.out.println("will return old object");
        return untitled;
    }
}
public String create() throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println("will persist object");
        System.out.println("and your object is" + untitled);
        facade.create(untitled);
        return "success";
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("fail at persisting the entity");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The if untitled == null should not be needed. You're probably doing something else wrong. PostConstruct runs before JSF calls any methods on your bean other than injection initialization.